# How to send the productIDs from a product catalog to java class?

Tags: java, forms, jsp, struts2

(This question is that that difficult but I could not solve it yet) I have a product catalog that is showing different values using < div > tag, there should be a button for user to add the chosen products to shopping basket but I do not know send the ProductsID to java class.

```
 Name:ProductA     Name:ProductB 
 Price:3.5         Price:5.0
 Add               Add
```

My code in JSP/struts2 is as following:

Here is a form that by receiving a value will populate the Friend.name in the  tag.

```
<sx:div>
   <div id="Name">name:${Friend.name}</div>
   <s:form action="myMethod" >
     <s:submit/>
   </s:form>
</sx:div>
```

Once the user clicks on the submit it goes to the required class and line 11 runs but the "name is: null" is shown.

```
private String name;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String myMethod() {
Line 11  System.out.println("in mymethod");  // output is : mymethod
     System.out.println("The name is:" + this.name); // output is: the name is: null
     return "SUCCESS";
}
```

I am not sure if it is caused because the jsp code is in AJAX tag there is another issue causing the problem.

It is weird as when I use

```
 <s:textfield name="Name" label="Name" />
```

and enter an input it accepts it and shows the value using this.name !!

**Another example** The HTML and JSP (new version) Code are as following:

```
  <s:form action="AddProduct" >
     <tr><td><div id="image"><img src=${Product.thumbNailUrl} alt="image"/></div></td></tr>
       <s:textfield name="Name" label="Name" />  
     <tr><td><div id="Name">Here:${Product.name}</div></td></tr>
     <s:hidden id="Name1" value="name1">${Product.name}</s:hidden>
     <s:label id="name2" name="name2" value="John"/>
     <tr><td><div id="Rate:">Rate:${Product.highRate}</div></td></tr>
     <tr><td><div id="Address">Address:${Product.address}</div></td></tr>
     <tr><td>
                  <s:submit/>
    </s:form>
```

********** HTML ********

```
  <tr><td><div id="Name">Here:Beaufort</div></td></tr>
     Beaufort<input type="hidden" name="" value="name1" id="Name1"/>
     <tr>
         <td class="tdLabel"></td>
         <td><label id="name2">John</label></td>
     </tr>

     <tr><td><div id="Rate:">Rate:437.19</div></td></tr>
     <tr><td><div id="Address">Address:33 Beaufort</div></td></tr>
     <tr><td>
                  <tr>

      <td colspan="2"><div align="right"><input type="submit" id="AddProduct_0" 
       value="Submit"/>
      </div></td>
       </tr>

    </table></form>
```

Comment: -1: the question is not detailed enough to understand what you want to do and where you are stuck. Kindly elaborate. Thank you

Comment: I suppose it is clear I have a list of products shown by table and <div> tag, there is a button to add them to the shopping cart, but I do not know how to send the details of products to java class. I have not write the code for this section yet thats why there is no code

Comment: @Down-voter, why did you vote it down? if its unclear let me know to rephrase it, I need my problem to be solve so I am not going to write an unclear question just for fun!!

Comment: ... it would help if you posted generated code of one of the products.

Comment: @vector, the other user who has the same problem, copied his code in his/her name is US USAMA please have a look at his answer. I have just edited the question as well.

Comment: That's not what I'm talking about, post the generated page source from browser. The stuff ajax/js renders. Not your jsp code.

Comment: @vector, thanks I have just added the html source and the new version of code.

Comment: @EmeEmertana removed the down-vote. Did you ever happen to mouse-over the down-vote arrow? if not then please do and you will get a tool-tip explaining why to down-vote :-) . And this is the best tool to get the attention of the OP to improve the question, since there are many who just post questions for fun and don't care later to update it so that they are answered. Good to hear you are not one of them.

Comment: @PrakashK, yes down-voter should have a look at the comments and the edit time before down voting a question, people are surprisingly weird when have a bit of power to make decisions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how much you are experienced with `struts` but I assume your question has a really simple solution:

**First**, you need to have a form. This form should contain anything you need to pass to your class. (*If you are new to `form`s, do a little google to find a variety of tutorials*)

**Second**, set your form's `action` to your java class which is responsible for processing it. (*If you are new to `controllers` google a bit for `struts` tutorials*)

**Third**, in that class receive the inputs and do as you want.

---

**UPDATED**

We have (kind of) the same similar situation. There are two options available:

**One** to have a hidden field and have the IDs there (hidden field or just simply do not show it in your page), so whenever an object is selected the ID will be sent too.

**Two** use hibernate 2nd level cache, and retrieve it using hibernate. Use `load` method to retrieve the ID from that cache.

Why level-2? Because it does not query the DB and is more efficient.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, the problem is that the table of product catalog is generated by ajax and I need to retrieve the id of the selected product and send the id  to the java class but not sure how to do it.

Comment: I have no idea about hibernate, and did the first option as illustrated in the question but it does not work.

Comment: I see that you left the `name` part blank. Why is that? How can you get the parameter later? Isn't it causing the problem?

Comment: Which name do you mean I cant find it

Comment: At the line  which you've written `BeauFort`. I'm not sure if this is causing the problem or not, but do you know that `name` parameter is more important than `ID`. Are you not confusing them with each other?

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you are populating the catalog on your view(html), may be you should keep a hidden field , which will store the productId of the corresponding product. So, whenever user adds the product to the shopping cart, you can easily get the id of that product and send it to server.

Comment: yes I used it but the value is empty, the one whose answer is before yours has also the same problem.

Comment: what is empty? productId? Once your page is loaded, check using firebug or any other development tool whether it is properly being populated or not

Comment: it is populated but the productId is empty.

Comment: so, you will have to look into the code which is actually populating the productId in your hidden field in your product catalog. Debug that code once with firebug. If you are still unable to resolve it, then post your code here.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17787/discussion-between-eme-emertana-and-sumit-desai)

Comment: it does not work when I look at the HTML code it shows <input type="hidden" name="" value="name1" id="Name1"/> and colored in red saying that it is misspelled element.

Comment: I changed it to <s:hidden id="Name" name="Name" value="%{value.name}"/>
but the value is still empty.

Comment: it's not working because you have not used property or name attribute.So, how will it copy that property in your respective field? You should use property="name" or name="name", and value=${value}, so that you will get it on server

Comment: thanks for your reply, I changed it to <s:hidden id="Name" name="Name" value="%{value.name}"/> but the value is still empty.

Comment: You have used Name in attribute and name in value. Alphabetically, both are different. Also, have you ensured that null property in incoming object is not null?

Comment: Yes I have ${value.name} in my div tag and its correct but %{value.name} in hidden tag is empty.

Comment: are you getting other values used with attribute name in server properly?Also, in the div, you have value of name property. Is it properly being populated?

Comment: my complete code is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12812805/how-to-pass-a-value-of-a-list-to-a-hidden-tag please have a look at it. thanks