# How to pass a value of a list to a hidden tag?

Tags: java, html, jsp, struts2, arraylist

I have the following code in my jsp:

```
<c:forEach var="value" items="${MyList}" varStatus="loop">
  <tr><td><div id="Name1">Here:${value.name}</div></td></tr>
  <s:hidden id="Name" name="Name" value="%{value.name}"/>
```

the html source is as following:

```
     <tr><td><div id="Name1">Here:My name is X</div></td></tr>
     <input type="hidden" name="Name" value="" id="Name"/>
```

As demonstrated the div tag is showing the value.name correctly but the value attribute of hidden tag is empty. I could not find any solution because most of the solutions were not related to list.
I changed it to `${value.name}` but ran into this error: "According to TLD or attribute directive in tag file, attribute value does not accept any expressions"

My completed JSP is as following:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>  


<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Register</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="Search">
        <label for="message">Travel details</label>
    <table border="1">


    <s:form action="Search_Search" >


      <td>
      <s:textfield name="City" label="City" /></td>
      <td><s:textfield name="HighRate" label="Budget" /></td>
      <td><s:textfield name="Adults" label="Adults"/></td>
      <td><s:textfield name="Childs" label="Child (less 15)"/></td>
      <td><s:select label="Prefered hotel rate" name="rate" list="rate" value="no preference"/></td> 
      <td><s:textfield name="Days" label="Days"/></td>
      <td><s:radio label="Is the budget fixed" name="BdgFixed" list="BdgFixed"
            value="defaultBudget"/>
      <td><s:submit/></td>

      </s:form>


    </table>


    </div>

    <sx:div>
                <table border="1">
                <tr>
                <c:forEach var="Hotel" items="${HotelsList}" varStatus="loop">
                 <c:set var="nameVar" scope="request" value="${Hotel.name}"/>
                 <c:if test="${not loop.first and loop.index % 3 == 0}">
                   </tr><tr>
                 </c:if>
                <td>

                  <div id="HotelInfo">



         <td>
         <s:form action="Search_AddHotel" >
         <tr><td><div id="image"><img src=${Hotel.thumbNailUrl} alt="image"/></div></td></tr>
           <s:textfield name="Name3" label="Budget" />  
         <tr><td><div id="Name1">Here:<c:out value="${nameVar}"/></div></td></tr>
         <s:hidden id="Name" name="Name" value='${nameVar}'/>
         <s:label id="name2" name="name2" value="John"/>
         <tr><td><div id="Highest Rate:">Rate:${Hotel.highRate}</div></td></tr>
         <tr><td><div id="Address">Address:${Hotel.address}</div></td></tr>
         <tr><td>
                      <s:submit/>
        </s:form>

         </td></tr>
          </td>

               </c:forEach>
                    </tr>
                </table>
   </sx:div>

</body>
</html>
```

My completed Java class is as following:

```
package com.funontour.controller;

import org.jdom.Document;
import org.jdom.Element;
import org.jdom.input.SAXBuilder;

import com.funontour.common.Hotels;
import com.funontour.model.DistanceModel;
import com.funontour.model.SearchModel;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.io.StringReader;

import javax.xml.soap.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;

public class SearchAction {

    private String Name;
    private String City;
    private String HighRate;
    private String Adults;
    private String Childs;
    private List HotelsList;
    private List<String> BdgFixed;
    private List<String> rate;
    private static final String Yes = "Yes";
    private static final String No = "No";

    public String execute() throws Exception {
        generateForm();
        // runClient(); //actual rate should be received
        // System.out.println("goes back to strut.xml");
        return "SUCCESS";
    }
    public String getName()
    {
        return Name;
    }
    public void setName(String name){
        this.Name = name;
    }
   public void AddHotel(){
       System.out.println("name is:"+Name);
       System.out.println("getName:" + getName());
       System.out.println("thisName" + this.Name);

   }
    public String Search() { // Country is set to AU
        System.out.println("In Search method of SearchAction");
        Showdetails();
        String result = SearchHotel();

        generateForm();  
        return result;
    }

    public void generateForm(){

        BdgFixed = new ArrayList<String>();
        BdgFixed.add(Yes);
        BdgFixed.add(No);

        rate = new ArrayList<String>();
        rate.add("1");
        rate.add("2");
        rate.add("3");
        rate.add("4");
        rate.add("5");
    }

    public void Showdetails(){
        System.out.println(this.City + " " + this.HighRate + " " + this.Adults + " " 
                + this.Childs + " " + this.rate+ " " + this.BdgFixed);
    }
    public String SearchHotel(){
        HotelsList = new ArrayList();
        SearchModel searchModel = new SearchModel();
        List inputs = new ArrayList<String>();


        //If some of these are not entered should ask again
        // for multiple choices do not work if nothing has been selected
        if(!getCity().isEmpty())
        inputs.add(getCity());
        else
            inputs.add("London");

        if(!getHighRate().isEmpty())
        inputs.add(getHighRate());
        else
            inputs.add("0");

        if(!getAdults().isEmpty())
        inputs.add(getAdults());
        else
            inputs.add("1");

        if(!getChilds().isEmpty())
        inputs.add(getChilds());
        else
            inputs.add("0");

        if(!getRate().isEmpty())
        inputs.add(this.rate.get(0).toString());
        else
            inputs.add("1");

        if(!getBdgFixed().isEmpty()) 
        inputs.add(this.BdgFixed.get(0).toString());   
        else
            inputs.add("Yes");

        if(searchModel.createMessage(inputs) == "SUCCESS")
        {
        System.out.println("SUCCESS");
        setHotelsList(searchModel.getHotelsList());
        return "SUCCESS";
        }
        System.out.println("Failed");
        return "SUCCESS";
    }
    /* Search for the distance      
    public String Search(){


    /*//Search for Suggestion
    public String Search(){
        System.out.println("In Search method");
        SearchModel sm = new SearchModel();
        sm.retrieveItems(getCity().toString());
        return "SUCCESS";
    }*/
    public String getCity() {
        return City;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        City = city;
    }

    public String getHighRate() {
        return HighRate;
    }

    public void setHighRate(String highRate) {
        HighRate = highRate;
    }

    public List getHotelsList() {
        return HotelsList;
    }

    public void setHotelsList(List hotelsList) {
        HotelsList = hotelsList;
    }

    public String getAdults() {
        return Adults;
    }

    public void setAdults(String adults) {
        Adults = adults;
    }

    public String getChilds() {
        return Childs;
    }

    public void setChilds(String childs) {
        Childs = childs;
    }

    public List<String> getBdgFixed() {
        return BdgFixed;
    }

    public void setBdgFixed(List<String> bdgFixed) {
        BdgFixed = bdgFixed;
    }

    public List<String> getRate() {
        return rate;
    }

    public void setRate(List<String> rate) {
        this.rate = rate;
    }

}
```

I used `%{nameVar}` also but the value is still empty. :( someone help plz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try not to use property names like `value`, `key`, etc., because they could be reserved keywords.

So change `value` to something different and see if is this works.

**EDIT:** 
Change this
 `<s:hidden id="Name" name="Name" value='${nameVar}'/>`

to
 `<s:hidden id="Name" name="Name" value="%{nameVar}"/>`

**Update:**

If you want to use `forEach` tag then use 
`<input type="hidden" name="Name" value="${nameVar}">`

or use `<s:iterator>` tag with
`<s:hidden id="Name" name="Name" value="%{nameVar}"/>`

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I have posted my code, it is not using any reserved key is it ?

Comment: I used it but the value is still empty its the HTML source <input type="hidden" name="Name" value="" id="Name"/>

Comment: Use struts2 `<s:iterator/>` tag not `<c:forEach>`.

Comment: @DaveNewton On using forEach one must use ${nameVar}, and this will not work inside struts tag. So solution is not to use forEach or not to use struts tag.

Comment: @AleksandrM forEach isn't a Struts tag, and the S2 request wrapper allows JSP EL to look into the value stack--it works just fine.

Comment: @DaveNewton Yes I am aware of that, but I am not saying that forEach will not work, what i am saiyng is `<s:hidden value="${nameVar}"/>` will NOT compile because of `$` sign.

Comment: @AleksandrM That's not a reason not to use c:forEach, that's a reason not to use JSP EL inside an S2 tag though. IMO when functionality overlaps the correct choice is to use JSTL/plain HTML.

Comment: @DaveNewton Agree, but if someone uses struts2 why not to use struts2 tags instead of jstl.

Comment: More eyes on jstl code. If there's *no* jstl used anywhere, then fine, but I tend to use standard functionality when it exists.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<c:forEach var="value" items="${MyList}" varStatus="loop">           
    <c:set var="nameVar" scope="request" value="${value.name}"/>    
    <tr>
        <td>
           <div id="Name1">Here: <c:out value="${nameVar}"/> </div>
           <s:hidden id="Name" name="Name" value='${nameVar}'/> 
        </td>
    </tr>          
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: it gives this error "According to TLD or attribute directive in tag file, attribute value does not accept any expressions" the eclipse also warns that "'value' does not support run time expressions"

Comment: can you share your complete jsp code with taglib included, also share controller code where you have MYList

Comment: I think HotelsList contaions object of Hotels. is this correct? , then please share Hotels Model Object fields. and which field value you want to display in hidden field in jsp page.

Comment: Also in your above complete jsp , you have wrong code line, it should be <c:set var="nameVar" scope="request" value="${Hotel.name}"/>

Comment: you are right it contains Hotel objects, it seems the model is correct as this line is properly working <div id="Name1">Here:<c:out value="${nameVar}"/></div> but the hidden tag one is empty, something should be wrong with the Hidden tag I suppose.

Comment: yeah changed it, now it gives "According to TLD or attribute directive in tag file, attribute value does not accept any expressions" on this line >> <s:hidden id="Name" name="Name" value='${nameVar}'/>

Comment: @EmeEmertana S2 tags accept only OGNL expressions, not JSP EL.

Comment: @DaveNewton, so whats your suggestion?

Comment: @EmeEmertana Use OGNL like I said?

Comment: @DaveNewton, I am newbie would you give an example or sample code I am sick of this problem

Comment: @EmeEmertana Have you looked at the S2 documentation? All this is discussed there.

Comment: @DaveNewton, whats that would you send me the link?

Comment: @EmeEmertana I don't understand, you ned a link to the documentation of the framework you're using?

Comment: @DaveNewton, no I mean I could not find the part that is related to this question, I checked out the hidden tag part but it did not help me much.